# Create Azure Deployment Package & deploy to cloud service

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-cloud-services

I have a web project and Azure cloud service deployment project. I am currently deploying to Azure cloud service manually by creating package and updating the package in Azure portal. I wanted to automate this process using PowerShell script. I found a blog which list out the steps, but it is very old. Also, I am not able to use exec msbuild command that is mentioned in this article. Can you help me how to following command? I am not able to execute this from powershell window.

```
exec { msbuild /p:Configuration=Release /p:DebugType=None /p:Platform=AnyCpu /p:OutputPath= /p:TargetProfile=Cloud /t:publish /verbosity:quiet }
```

> https://www.kenneth-truyers.net/2014/02/06/deploying-cloud-services-to-azure-with-powershell/

Comment: You may consider doing it through Azure DevOps pipeline: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/apps/cd/deploy-cloudservice-cloudservice?view=azure-devops

Answer (score 0):

Are you using azure devops? If yes, and automating the deployment of your website to cloud is the problem then consider using pipelines? I hope I understood your question correctly!

Comment: I can use the Azure devops pipeline, but wanted to use Powershell.